# matplotlib seaborn long rownames affect other subplots' axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a table and I really like seaborn. So I wrote a simple function that returns a seaborn heatmap and fills the cells with some grey color.
My problem is, when I use that table in a subplot, other plots along the vertivcal axes are getting shrunk to the width of the axis that I plot the seaborn heatmap on.

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotTable(tableDf, ax=None):
    s = len(tableDf), len(tableDf.columns)
    dataZeros = np.zeros(s)
    dataTableFake = pd.DataFrame(dataZeros, index=tableDf.index, columns=tableDf.columns)
    dataTable = tableDf.values.astype(str)

    col = ["#dbdada"]
    my_cmap = ListedColormap(col)
    ax = sns.heatmap(dataTableFake, cmap=my_cmap, annot_kws={"size": 8}, cbar=False, linewidths=0.5,
                     square=False, ax=ax, annot = dataTable, fmt = '')
    ax.xaxis.tick_top()
    ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)


table = pd.DataFrame(dict(value01=1.01,
                          value02=2.02,
                          value03=3.03),
                          index=["This is a pretty long index and I dont't want it to shrink the other subplots"])

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 0])

plotTable(tableDf=table, ax=ax1)
plt.tight_layout()
```

creates the following plot:

[image]

I don't want the second axis (i.e. ax2) to be affected by the length of the rownames in ax1. I hope this makes clear what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a gridspec over 2 rows and 3 columns and place the "table" in the rightmost subplot in the first row. The other plot can then span over all 3 subplot positions in the second row.

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 3)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 2])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, :])
```

Finally, don't call `tight_layout` as this messes everything up. If you need to adjust the spacings, manually set them using `plt.subplots_adjust(...)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ernes. I see. No chance of using tight_layout here?

Comment: As I said, tight_layout will try to interprete the layout and it will not do it in the way you intend it to. But why would you need it anyways?

Comment: It takes automatically care of overlapping axis titles which is convenient for the plot I need.

Comment: As said, use e.g. `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)` instead of `tight_layout`. Chose the number such they won't overlap.